# DataGrid.ItemsSource Error

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have a DataGrid and do the the insertion follows:

```
ctrlSetores.InsertSetores(cdsetor, descricao)
ds = ctrlSetores.CarregaAllSetores()
dtgGenerico.ItemsSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
```

It's fine, but when i delete

```
cdset = dtgGenerico.SelectedItem(0).ToString
ctrlSetores.DeleteSetores(cdset)
ds = ctrlSetores.CarregaAllSetores()
dtgGenerico.ItemsSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
```

Show the error:

> object variable or with block variable not set

Can someone help me solve this error.

Obs: The Insert method works perfectly this error only occurs in the delete.

Comment: The erro occur in:
dtgGenerico.ItemsSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView

Comment: Is any row in that table? Is all the Row in that Table are Deleted? Default view is null or empty object? Try this ItemSource with any other ItemsControl like ListBox or ListView.. is the Deletion reflects?

Comment: I own four rows in the table when I delete something, this error happens. The same error happens when I try to add a record with a selected row. I believe that this error happens because the row is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where my mistake was, he was in the SelectionChanged event that tried to fill my Textboxs with the row deleted.